# Is it okay to multiply both sides of an inequality with a positive number if one side is 0?

Tags: inequality

I was wondering if it would be okay to multiply both sides of an inequality by a positive number $n$ if the inequality is the following:

$$-2/n < 0$$

And thus getting that $-2<0$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is always valid to do the same thing to both sides of an inequality, providing that it preserves ordering. Multiplication by positive numbers preserves ordering.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few cases to consider. If $n = 0$, then the inequality is nonsense.

If $n > 0$, then we may multiply both sides by $n$ to obtain
$$
-2 < 0
$$
If $n < 0$, then we may multiply both sides by $n$ to obtain
$$
-2 > 0
$$
The fact that $-2 > 0$ is not true tells us that the case $n < 0$ has no solutions (supposing there were solutions with $n < 0$ produced a contradiction).

Thus, all we've managed to demonstrate with this approach is that $n > 0$.

It turns out that $n > 0$ precisely describes the solutions to this inequality. To see this, observe that $-2$ divided by any positive number is indeed less than $0$.

The moral of the story is that we can say nothing about what multiplying both sides of the inequality by $n$ does to the inequality without first establishing that $n$ is strictly positive or strictly negative.